# JS France phone number format

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, replace, safari

I want to format French phone number on input.
For example if inputed

0XXXXXXXXX need transform to 0X XX XX XX XX , which one I already achieved with replace:

```
.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
```

But I also want to format if number starts with +33

+33XXXXXXXXX need transform to +33 X XX XX XX XX

How can I achieve that?
note: I need it in same input

Thanks

Comment: Alternatively try [`.replace(/\+\d\d|\d\d?(?=(?:\d\d)+\b)/g,'$& ')`](https://tio.run/##RYu9DsIgGEV3nuIbjECoVMX/pnbyKcSBAlYNKQ0QF/XZ0U4uN@ck5z7UU0Ud7kOa9d7YnJ1NEFOIUMMZMyEWS7Fab7a7PS7w/C@XCqEx41cfTkrfyO9whBcC0L6P3lnufEciD3ZwSltSSiaNNO9xGtLUpDmMSJlsadkVgCdTwJRW6ENz/gI) also see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zbYsD7/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, add to your expression a negative lookbehind for +3 `(?<!\+3)` so it should not add a space after the +3

secondly, add another option with a logical OR operator `|` with a positive lookbehind for +33 `\B(?<=\+33)`

so the final result will be:

```
.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))(?<!\+3)|\B(?<=\+33)/g, " ");
```

Comment: It throw error on IOS "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name" @MordyStern

Comment: seems like lookbehind is not supported on ISO https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind you can do two separate replaces `.replace(/(^\+33)(\d)(\d+)/, '$1 $2 $3').replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, " ");`